# How to install Punkt Sentence Tokenizer

Tags: nltk

I come across the model: Punkt Sentence Tokenizer, but don't know how to install it. Could you please provide me with a help. Thanks

Comment: should start off by looking at the [documentation](http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/tokenize/punkt.html)

Comment: Within Python: `import nltk; nltk.download('punkt')` or on command-line `python -m nltk.download punkt`

Comment: Thanks a lot. I got an error "Punkt" is not recognised.